# Jquery AJAX PHP MySQL not returning any data (Failing with PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I keep getting a failure from my AJAX.  I have checked all my PHP in a separate file and it all seems to be working fine.  No problems and the json_encode of the created array seems to be good with all the field names and values.

Because my understanding of AJAX and JSON is not very good, I expect I have missed some obvious point.  I have checked the CONSOLE in Google Chrome Inspect Elements and there are no messages.

JS:

```
        function processSearch(){
            alert('Doing Search');
            $.ajax({
                url: "WCITSearch.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $('#searchFORM').serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("SUCCESS from PHP:");
                    $('#results').html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("FAILURE from PHP:");
                    $('#results').html(data);
                }

            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

PHP:

```
    $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die(mysql_error());

$dbs = mysql_select_db($database, $connection) or die(mysql_error());  // Select the datbase

// 2) Query database for data
$select = "SELECT vehGrpName, vehTitle, vehDescrip FROM vehicles LIMIT 20";
$result = mysql_query($select) or die(mysql_error());          //query
$recs = array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $recs[] = array('vehicles'=>$post);
    }
}
// 3) echo result as json 
echo json_encode($recs);
```

I have been struggling for a couple of days now, but I am a loss as to what to test for next.

Any pointers / help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the failure? At which point does it occure - during the request or the response? Is ist just empty data or nothing at all? Does your script enter the success-function? Or the error-function? And it seems to be missing both closing brackets from `ajax({});`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  The missing closing AJAX are there.  They got lost in my copy-pasting.  The error is in the Alert being executed of the error: option of the AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for all help.  I now understand a bit better and have learned to use `console.log()`.  The error: option is only executed when there is a problem with the PHP script and I found this because of the following code I found somewhere `error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {      alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);}` and I could see I had messed up my working test of the PHP with the actual PHP.  If I implement this in future, I will hopefully get less problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the ajax error callback is triggered, it doesn't mean that "php fails" but "request fails".

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

So I think you should verify the `url` attribute. Are you sure `WCITSearch.php` and your script are on the same level?
However you can use `network` tab in webkit developer tools.

Comment: The url is correct and in the same directory as the calling javascript.  They are one level down from `public_html`.

Comment: `WCITSearch.php /WCIT POST 200 OK text/html jquery.min.js:4 Script 235B 20B 948ms 940ms`  Hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, I don't see why the error callback is called as the request returns OK. Does it return some JSON?